# Retrieving the last record in each group

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table, `communicats`, in my SQL Server database that contains data as below:

```
Id       Current_Status    Date       Other_Columns  
--------------------------------------------------- 
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-01-25  |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-02-17  |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-02-27  |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-02-28  |               
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-05-13  |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-06-11  |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-06-28  |               
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-07-13  |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-07-19  |
```

I want to format data like this:

```
Id       Current_Status    Date       Row_ID    Other_Columns
-------------------------------------------------------------
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-01-25  |  1     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-02-17  |  1     |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-02-27  |  2     |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-02-28  |  2     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-05-13  |  3     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-06-11  |  3     |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-06-28  |  4     |                  
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-07-13  |  5     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-07-19  |  5     |
```

I tried something like that:

```
SELECT 
    *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Id, Current_status) as Row_Id
FROM 
    communicats
```

But result of that query is only:

```
Id       Current_Status    Date       Row_ID    Other_Columns
-------------------------------------------------------------
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-01-25  |  1     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-02-17  |  1     |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-02-27  |  2     |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-02-28  |  2     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-05-13  |  1     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-06-11  |  1     |              
3aaab2ac |  F          | 2021-06-28  |  2     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-07-13  |  1     |              
3aaab2ac |  T          | 2021-07-19  |  1     |
```

So I would like to give each group containing the same status an ascending Id number.

Necessarily, I need this to remain in a form that does not shorten the number of records.

How can I get this result?

Comment: This is a type of *gaps-and-islands* problem, if you're looking for the term

Answer (score 4):

This is a type of gaps-and-islands problem and a common solution is:

1. `Lag` the 'Current_Status' and detect when it changes.
2. Add 1 every time is changes and sum this value.

```
declare @communicats table (Id varchar(8), Current_Status varchar(1), [Date] date);

insert into @communicats (Id, Current_Status, [Date])
values
 ('3aaab2ac', 'T', '2021-01-25')
,('3aaab2ac', 'T', '2021-02-17')             
,('3aaab2ac', 'F', '2021-02-27')
,('3aaab2ac', 'F', '2021-02-28')
,('3aaab2ac', 'T', '2021-05-13')
,('3aaab2ac', 'T', '2021-06-11')
,('3aaab2ac', 'F', '2021-06-28')
,('3aaab2ac', 'T', '2021-07-13')
,('3aaab2ac', 'T', '2021-07-19');

WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *
        , CASE WHEN LAG(Current_Status) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) <> Current_Status THEN 1 ELSE 0 END LaggedStatus
    FROM @communicats
)
SELECT id, Current_Status, [Date]
    , 1 + SUM(LaggedStatus) OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) Row_ID
FROM cte
ORDER BY [Date];
```

Returns:

| id | Current_Status | Date | Row_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 3aaab2ac | T | 2021-01-25 | 1 |
| 3aaab2ac | T | 2021-02-17 | 1 |
| 3aaab2ac | F | 2021-02-27 | 2 |
| 3aaab2ac | F | 2021-02-28 | 2 |
| 3aaab2ac | T | 2021-05-13 | 3 |
| 3aaab2ac | T | 2021-06-11 | 3 |
| 3aaab2ac | F | 2021-06-28 | 4 |
| 3aaab2ac | T | 2021-07-13 | 5 |
| 3aaab2ac | T | 2021-07-19 | 5 |

Note: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML (as shown here) you make it much easier for people to assist.

Comment: Yes, this is the common solution to a Gaps & Island question. This solution should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score -2):

Your target table des not make any sense. As far as I understood, you can try using window functions `rank()` or `dense_rank()`. But for using that you need to be clear on which column you are going to order the rank by.

Comment: Yes, I know that. You can treat this table as a log table, where it needs to number the records with a higher Id number only when the status has changed from T to N and the opposite.